# Big lists in a relational DB

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to store a list of items and that list belongs to a single user. The lists are going to be huge, so this has to be done as efficiently as possible. The lists also have to be modifiable to a small degree (able to add new items).

This is my (possible) solution:
Have a table `items`, where we store the data of our items. Table `lists` contains info about our lists (name, user_id etc). Table `lists_lengths` contains our lists lengths, e.g:

```
list_id | item_id_start | item_id_end
------------------------------------
1       | 1             | 200
2       | 201           | 220
1       | 221           | 300
```

If the lists get a lot of modifications, this might end up being a poor design though. Is this good or is the blatant `list_id` in the `items` table just the way to go?

Comment: List 1 contains 1-200 and 221-300, correct?  And no item shows up in two lists, correct?

Comment: How big is "huge?" Thousands, millions, billions?

Comment: How's about you do it the standard way, test its performance, then tweak if necessary?

Comment: Correct. Each list can contain up to 500,000 items. Each user is going to have 5-20 of them. There's enough users that optimization is something that I'm worried about.

Comment: What would the "standard" way be? `list_id` in `items` table? I might just go with that and restructure if issues arise.

Answer (score 1):

Once the table gets really big, you will find that looking up an item to find out what list it is in becomes painfully slow.

I discuss that, plus provide efficient code, in my [blog on ip-ranges](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges).  Your use case (non-overlapping ranges of items "owned" by various "lists") seems to be the same problem.